# How can I override all the fields in a mutable reference using another struct?

Tags: rust, mutable

How can I avoid listing all the fields when using `x` to populate `input`?

```rust
struct StructX {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}

trait TraitY {
    fn foo(info: &mut StructX) -> bool;
}

impl TraitY for SomeZ {
    fn foo(input: &mut StructX) -> bool {
        let mut x = StructX { /*....*/ };
        // do something with x, then finally:
        input.a = x.a;
        input.b = x.b;
    }
}
```

In C++ it would be just `input = x`, but that doesn't work in Rust. Note that this is an "interface" so I cannot change the type of `input` to something else.

Comment: Note that references in Rust are most similar to pointers in C++, not to references. If you want to reassign a struct behind a pointer, you also need to dereference in C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to dereference `input` ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=763785a04eccd40b938998f7a3f9f8fd)):

```rust
struct StructX {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}

trait TraitY {
    fn foo(info: &mut StructX) -> bool;
}

impl TraitY for SomeZ {
    fn foo(input: &mut StructX) -> bool {
        let mut x = StructX { /*....*/ };
        // do something with x, then finally:
        *input = x;

        return true;
    }
}
```

---

If you wouldn't like to move `x` into `input` then you can use [Clone::clone_from](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#method.clone_from)

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d37c0f9cf5b315202eee9f8450f5271c)

```
#[derive(Clone)]
struct StructX {
    a: u32,
    b: u32,
}


trait TraitY {
    fn foo(info: &mut StructX) -> bool;
}

struct SomeZ{}

impl TraitY for SomeZ {
    fn foo(input: &mut StructX) -> bool {
        let mut x = StructX { a:42, b:56};
        x.a = 43;
        input.clone_from(&x);
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work (in my actual case). This is not assigning the values to the original struct, it's moving "x" into input. In my actual code the assignment is inside of a loop and I cannot move "x" (since I'm using it afterwards), and I don't want to Copy it. I want to preserve the performance of assigning the fields. Let me know if I'm wrong about how Copy works.

Comment: Hi @xixixao. Did you looked at [`Clone::clone_from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#method.clone_from)

Comment: that's the right way, thank you. If you post an answer (should mention `#[derive(Clone)]`) I'll accept it, thanks!

Comment: @xixixao, does new version of the answer looks good for you?