# Can replacing a String in a mutable reference leak memory?

Tags: rust

I stumbled upon the following scenario:

```rust
fn compute_values(value: &mut String) {
    // the first computation should always work:
    let computed_value = String::from("computed value");
    // override the default String with the computed value:
    *value = computed_value;
    // some more code that returns a Result with values or an error message
}

fn main() {
    let mut value = String::from("default value");
    compute_values(&mut value);
    println!("value: {value}")
}
```

This code compiles with my `rustc 1.74.1 (a28077b28 2023-12-04)` and outputs `value: computed value` as I'd expect, but the question is, if that code leaks memory.

As I understand it, `*value = computed_value;` moves `computed_value` into `*value` and it is no longer available (The rust compiler confirms this, I cannot `println!("{computed_value}");` afterwards.) and not de-allocated when the function scope ends. As this line is effectively assigning a `struct String` to a `struct String`, I'm guessing all struct fields are copied to the location of the original struct. But once the original contained `&str` reference is overwritten, there is no way to de-allocate the original heap memory that the old `&str` pointed to. As I'm not using any unsafe Rust and Rust seems to be memory-safe, I can only imagine that the original memory is de-allocated automatically before the assignment happens, but I couldn't find any information on that topic.

I found the following articles that didn't answer my question:

- [Is there a way to update a string in place in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68151743/is-there-a-way-to-update-a-string-in-place-in-rust)
- [How can I swap in a new value for a field in a mutable reference to a structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098694/how-can-i-swap-in-a-new-value-for-a-field-in-a-mutable-reference-to-a-structure)
- [How can I override all the fields in a mutable reference using another struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105258/how-can-i-override-all-the-fields-in-a-mutable-reference-using-another-struct)

The answers named [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html), [`std::mem::swap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.swap.html) and [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) which lead me to believe that using one of these is necessary in this case.

I also checked the official rust documentation but didn't find anything.

My questions are:

1. Is this code leaking memory?
2. Is non-unsafe Rust supposed to be memory safe even when replacing values of mutable references?
3. Is there any (official) documentation on the dereference assignment?

P.S.: Theoretically Rust might optimize `let mut value = String::from("default value");` such that the `String` `value` points to the string constant and not a location on the heap. This would then not make it necessary to de-allocate the memory. But the whole thing also works when you read a `value` from stdin and the whole thing must then be placed on the heap necessarily.

## Answer

After reading @cyqsimon's answer (which is great btw), I understood that this question really has nothing to do with references and is instead about dropping values when they are replaced. Armed with this new insight, I found [this Rustonomicon article](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/drop-flags.html) which fully answers my question and also talks about what happens when variables are only initialized and therefore dropped under certain conditions.

Comment: I would suppose that `drop()` of the old value is called just after the update. If you need the old value (without dropping), you have to swap/replace it.

Comment: The assignment you have looks very common, and you don't need to worry about the old string that was assigned to `value`. It will be cleaned up and there won't be a leak. And yes, **safe** rust is memory safe and the compiler will prevent you from violating that safety.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this code leaking memory?

No it is not. The old `String` struct is no longer owned by anything after the assignment, so it's automatically dropped (and therefore properly cleaned up).

---

> Is non-unsafe Rust supposed to be memory safe even when replacing values of mutable references?

Rust's memory safety guarantees many things - not leaking memory is not one of them. In fact, there is explicitly a [`Box::leak`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.leak) function that does exactly what you think it does. In this specific case, I suppose it could leak memory with an improperly implemented [`Drop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Drop.html) trait, although usually this is not something you would have to worry about.

---

> Is there any (official) documentation on the dereference assignment?

This "drop the old value" behaviour is a part of the assignment operation, rather than of the dereference operation. It is documented [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#basic-assignments). (Thanks @user2722968)

---

As of `std::mem::{swap, take, replace}`, these are safe abstractions that are intended to satisfy safe Rust's stipulation that all values must be valid at all times. Without them, if you ever want to move a value out from a mutable reference, semantically there would be an instant where the variable binding is undefined, which again is not allowed in safe Rust. If you take a look at the source code of these functions (they are rather simple), all they are doing is memcopy.

In this case, if you want to keep `String::from("default value")` after the reassignment as opposed to discarding this value, you would use `std::mem::replace`.

> Theoretically Rust might optimize `let mut value = String::from("default value");` such that the `String` `value` points to the string constant and not a location on the heap. This would then not make it necessary to de-allocate the memory. But the whole thing also works when you read a `value` from stdin and the whole thing must then be placed on the heap necessarily.

Not relevant to this question, but I don't believe small string optimisation is implemented on Rust (and in fact it might not be possible to implement in Rust). I recall Jack O'Connor briefly talked about why this is the case in [his excellent video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IPmRDS0OSxM).

Comment: I would agree that the specific wording in the book can probably be improved. I too cannot find any explicit documentation on what happens on reassignment.

Comment: This is covered in [the reference wrt to Basic Assignment](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#basic-assignments): "It [then] has the effect of first dropping the value at the assigned place, [...]". Here `*value` is the "assigned place" (technically, the [assignee expression](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions.html#place-expressions-and-value-expressions)). So we first evaluate `String::new()`(which could `panic!()`, btw), then `drop()` whatever is at `*value`, and then `move`/`copy` the value we got from `String::new()` into `*value`.

Comment: @user2722968 Ah yes thank you. Great find. I'll update my answer if you don't mind.

Comment: SSO is absolutely possible to implement in Rust (there are crates that do it), but not in safe code. `std::String` not doing SSO is a design choice (now fixed due to backwards compatibility), not a language limitation.

Comment: @SebastianRedl not the way C++ does it - with the string having a pointer to itself, that requires move constructors which Rust does not have.

Comment: @IvanC Rust can't do it this way, true. C++ can, but actual implementations might not, because it trades off code simplicity for memory (you could store more chars in the space where the pointer is). stdlibc++ has the pointer, libc++ doesn't.

Comment: Your answer helped me to better understand my question and find an article in the Rustonomicon about this topic. Thank you and @user2722968 as well. :)
(I updated my question to include the article.)